# Помогите оптимизировать метод

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Нужно реализовать такой вот метод, он работает, но заказчик ругается на то, что `FillMatrix` работает неэффективно, помогите пожалуйста как-либо оптимизировать код, буду благодарен

> Класс `SquareMatrix` - квадратная матрица, содержащая числа типа int. Должен быть открытым и содержать следующие открытые члены:
>
> - Конструктор от 1 параметра типа `uint matrixDimension` - создаёт квадратную матрицу размера `matrixDimension` X `matrixDimension`, заполненную нулями;
> - Метод void `FillMatrix()` - заполняет по строкам элементы матрицы с консоли (начиная с верхней строки). Ввод каждой строки осуществляется до первой правильной попытки. При этом некорректными стоит считать не только строки, содержащие не числа типа `int`, но и строки с лишними пробелами или строки, содержащие больше/меньше элементов, чем требуется в соответствии с размерностью матрицы. При каждом некорректном вводе строки метод должен выводить сообщение: `Incorrect input, expected <длина измерения матрицы> ints separated by spaces.` Обратите внимание, что в случае ошибки метод НЕ должен откидывать уже корректно считанные строки;
> - Метод `void Print()` - печатает матрицу как набор чисел, разделённых пробелами по строчкам (каждая новая строка матрицы - на отдельной строке);
>   Свойство только для чтения `uint Size` - количество элементов матрицы;
>   Свойство только для чтения `uint DimensionLength` - количество элементов в строке матрицы;
> - Индексатор типа `int`, принимающий 2 параметра типа `int` с именами `x` и `y` - возвращает элемент матрицы со строкой с номером x и столбцом с номером y (при чтении) или присваивает значение по указанным индексам (при записи). Проверки границ осуществлять не требуется;
> - Метод `bool TrySum(SquareMatrix other, out SquareMatrix result)` - складывает матрицы одинакового размера и сохраняет результат в result, если матрицы действительно имеют одинаковую длину измерения, возвращая true. В противном случае метод кладёт в result значение null и возвращает false;
> - Метод `bool TrySubtract(SquareMatrix other, out SquareMatrix result)` - выполняет вычитание матриц одинакового размера и сохраняет результат в `result`, если матрицы действительно имеют одинаковую длину измерения, возвращая `true`. В противном случае метод кладёт в `result` значение `null` и возвращает false;
> - Метод `SquareMatrix Multiply(int value)` - выполняет умножение всех элементов матрицы на переданное число, возвращает результат в виде новой матрицы того же размера;
> - Метод `bool TryMatrixMultiply(SquareMatrix other, out SquareMatrix result)` - выполняет матричное умножение матриц одинакового размера и сохраняет результат в `result`, если матрицы действительно имеют одинаковую длину измерения, возвращая `true`. В противном случае метод кладёт в `result` значение `null` и возвращает `false`;
> - Метод `SquareMatrix Transpose()` - возвращает транспонированную копию данной матрицы;

```
class SquareMatrix
{
    int[,] Matrix;
    public int this[int x, int y]
    {
        get => Matrix[x, y];
        set => Matrix[x, y] = value;
    }
    private uint size;
    private uint dimensionLength;
    public SquareMatrix(uint matrixDimension)
    {
        Matrix = new int[matrixDimension, matrixDimension];
        size = (uint)Matrix.Length;
        dimensionLength = (uint)Matrix.GetLength(0);
    }
    public uint Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        private set { }
    }
    public uint DimensionLength
    {
        get
        {
            return dimensionLength;
        }

        private set { }
    }
    public void FillMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            string StrMatrixLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (FillChecker(StrMatrixLine))
            {
                int[] IntMatrixLine = StrMatrixLine.Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
                for (uint ii = 0; ii < Matrix.GetLength(0); ii++)
                {
                    Matrix[i, ii] = IntMatrixLine[ii];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Incorrect input, expected {Matrix.GetLength(0)} ints separated by spaces.");
                --i;
            }
           
        }
    }
    bool FillChecker(string StrMatrixLine)
    {
        if (
            (Matrix.GetLength(0) - 1) == StrMatrixLine.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace))
        {
            string[] MatrixLineChecker = StrMatrixLine.Split();
                for (int i = 0; i < MatrixLineChecker.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(MatrixLineChecker[i],out int IntMatrixLine))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (uint ii = 0; ii < Matrix.GetLength(1); ii++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{Matrix[i, ii]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public bool TrySum(SquareMatrix other, out SquareMatrix result)
    {
        if (Matrix.GetLength(0) == other.Matrix.GetLength(0))
        {
            result = new SquareMatrix((uint)Matrix.GetLength(0));
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < Matrix.GetLength(0); ii++)
                {
                    other.Matrix[i, ii] += Matrix[i, ii];
                }
            }
            result.Matrix= other.Matrix;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool TrySubtract(SquareMatrix other, out SquareMatrix result)
    {
        if (Matrix.GetLength(0) == other.Matrix.GetLength(0))
        {
            result = new SquareMatrix((uint)Matrix.GetLength(0));
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < Matrix.GetLength(0); ii++)
                {
                    result.Matrix[i,ii]=other.Matrix[i, ii] - Matrix[i, ii];
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public SquareMatrix Multiply(int value)
    {
        SquareMatrix result = new SquareMatrix((uint)Matrix.GetLength(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < Matrix.GetLength(0); ii++)
            {
                result.Matrix[i, ii]= Matrix[i, ii]*value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public bool TryMatrixMultiply(SquareMatrix other, out SquareMatrix result)
    {
        if (Matrix.GetLength(0) == other.Matrix.GetLength(0))
        {
            result = new SquareMatrix((uint)Matrix.GetLength(0));
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < other.Matrix.GetLength(1); ii++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < other.Matrix.GetLength(0); j++)
                    {
                        result.Matrix[i, ii] += Matrix[i, j] * other.Matrix[j, ii];
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public SquareMatrix Transpose()
    {
        SquareMatrix result = new SquareMatrix((uint)Matrix.GetLength(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < Matrix.GetLength(0); ii++)
            {
                result.Matrix[i, ii] = Matrix[ii, i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: "заказчик ругается на то, что FillMatrix работает бесполезно" - что это значит?

Comment: @igor метод выполняет двойную работу преобразования сначала в FillMatrix зачем в Checker нужно оптимизировать, помогите с этим пожалуйста

Comment: бесполезно = неэффективно? замените слово, а то абсурд какой-то получается.

Comment: Не буду помогать, так как не вижу, где вызывается приведенный код.

Comment: Точно, как это использовать - не понятно. Что оно должно делать - не понятно. Говорите про один метод, показываете 2: нужно выбрать самому, в какой смотреть? `_matrix` - что такое, где оно объявляется?

Comment: добавил оставшийся код и задание, чтобы было более понятно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Стало заметно лучше, сейчас посмотрю, что здесь можно сделать.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Как-то вы вставили код с ошибками, он не компилируется, перепроверьте синтаксис, у вас потеряны скобки, может удалили где-то случайно. `private readonly uint _size = (uint)_matrix.Length;` вот это тоже не компилируется. Если вы утверждаете, что код рабочий - вставляйте рабочий код. Быть может это вообще надо удалить, потому что далее в коде оно нигде не используется.

Comment: Есть дополнительные файлы, в котором вызывается данный class, при необходимости могу прикрепить

Comment: Я не про дополнительные файлы, я про синтаксические ошибки в именно показанном коде. Скопируйте его, вставьте к себе в студию и проверьте сами, это же не сложно, и поправить не сложно. Просто приведите код в порядок.

Comment: закинул изначальный код, видимо при оптимизации ошибок наделал, так все работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кода много, весь смотреть не буду. Касательно метода, вот решение, а ниже расскажу, что к чему.

```cs
private void ThrowInvalidInput(int expectedLength) 
    => throw new FormatException($"Incorrect input, expected {expectedLength} ints separated by spaces.");

public void FillMatrix()
{
    int size = _matrix.GetLength(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($"matrix[{i}]: ");
        string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        try
        {
            if (tokens.Length != size)
                ThrowInvalidInput(size);

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(tokens[j], out int number))
                    _matrix[i, j] = number;
                else
                    ThrowInvalidInput(size);
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            --i;
        }
    }
}
```

- Называйте переменные проще и понятнее, но старайтесь не использовать сокращения. Весь успех именования переменных, классов и методов заключается в том, насколько легко другим разработчиками читать ваш код.
- Чтобы не бодаться с переходами, прерванием циклов и прочим, проще всего бросать исключение. Я бы, честно говоря, выдавал бы более подробные сообщения об ошибках, но ТЗ есть ТЗ.
- Много лишних телодвижений, зачем-то прикрутили Linq. Да, красиво, но как вы словите ошибку количества элементов не распарсив все что можно в числа? К тому же в вашем коде легко может возникнуть исключение при вводе какого-нибудь `ыыы` в консоль, и приложение упадет, а это несоответствует ТЗ. Ловите ошибки поэтапно, сначала длину, потом парсить числа, некуда спешить.
- Чтобы не дергать один и тот же метод `GetLength(0)`, его результат можно закешировать локально в переменную, он же всегда одно и то же возвращает во время выполнения метода, верно?
- Немного интерактивность, чтобы пользователь вообще понимал, что происходит - `Console.Write($"matrix[{i}]: ");`. Желательно пользователю до начала метода сообщить, сколько ему вводить то вообще надо. Допишите это под себя.

Comment: Благодарю! Сейчас буду разбираться